# Laptop won't start after BIOS update

Tags: laptop, bios

I have an HP Probook 4540s laptop. I recently updated its BIOS from HP's website. After the installation the laptop restarted, but since then there is no display. I waited for an hour until the battery ran down, after when I plugged it in to the power supply it's the same:

- Capslock light on the keyboard is continuously blinking.
- The fan is running faster than the usual speed. I can tell this from the sound.

And no display. I waited for more than hour for any response, but there was none. I searched the internet and found out that a lot people don't update their BIOS in HP laptops. I don't know why the official HP website even makes such updates available.

Is there a way I can reset the BIOS, hard reset, through USB of something? I have another PC with which I can download anything if it's required. Can anyone please help?

---

**UPDATE**

I also tried to recover BIOS through [UEFI USB method](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=uk&lc=en&docname=c02693833), but nothing happens after pressing "Win" + "B" and powering on USB led flashes for few seconds and than everything is same.

Comment: On desktops I would try to pull the CMOS battery for 30 seconds, but on a laptop that's not so easy and you'll probably void your warranty. I don't know if anyone knows a better solution for this, but imho the best thing you could try is sending the laptop back to HP for warranty.

Comment: Thankyou for replying, yes for desktop CMOS usually works for BIOS issues but neither i know where the CMOS is neither i want to do that because laptop is just 1 months old and in warranty the only reason behind why i am trying to resolve it on my own is, I have got a paper in 2 days and at warranty its gonna take weeks.

P.S. I guess ppl just like to downvote questions they cant answer.

Comment: can you enter BIOS?

Comment: Pulling the CMOS backup battery, or setting a reset jumper, clears the RTC and firmware settings memory but does not restore the firmware (BIOS, UEFI) binary image to some previous form.

Comment: @maven If the laptop is a month old, you should be able to take it back to the shop you purchased it from for them to exchange it for another. If not, then I'd go with what Forza said about sending it to HP.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing exactly the same problem, and resolved it with the following process:

- Press the computer power button and then the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key
- Now, press <kbd>F10</kbd>
- Pick these options: `Restore Defaults` → `Reset BIOS security to factory default`
- Answer "**Yes**" when asked, then press the key corresponding to the option `Save Changes and Exit`.
- You system will reboot now. If you're  asked if you want to use the fingerprint authentication method, answer "**Ignore**".